# don't know how to merge commits to origin/master

Tags: git

i created 3 commits. after that i've tried to push my changes to origin/master but then i detected that i'm currently in no branch. After that i've tried to merge the new commits to origin/master but it failed.
This is the current git reflog:

```
e664a6d HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from e664a6d3a47e7036f61d47e69f91bd20235d59b0 to master
e664a6d HEAD@{1}: merge master: Fast-forward
9f5948d HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to origin/master
e664a6d HEAD@{3}: merge HEAD@{3}: Fast-forward
9f5948d HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from dc325aeb1866e54d068c103cbc75910d4c464d59 to master
dc325ae HEAD@{5}: commit: remove debug from app.php
f5f2d7b HEAD@{6}: commit: add new results to listing
```

Can anybody tell me what i must to do merge HEAD@{4}-HEAD@{6} into my origin/master and go back to the branch to work with it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and reset `master` on `HEAD@{4}`:

```
git checkout -B master dc325aeb186
```

Then try to push.

Note: in all your tests, don't forget to save (or at least `git stash`) any untracked file.